# Can not see the Jade-Bootstrap navigation bar after moving to header.jade

Tags: pug

home.jade:

```
extends layout
block body
    +navbar("...","dropdown_menu","inverse")
        +nav_item("index.html","active") Home
        +nav_item("h...") Chat
    .container
```

layout.jade:

```
extends ../node_modules/jade-bootstrap/_bootstrap
doctype html
html
    head
        block head
            block title
                title Program Name
            block meta
    body
        include header

        block content

        include footer
```

After moving the three nav lines to header.jade and removing the leading tabs, the navigation bar was not visible anymore.

header.jade (originally):

```
+navbar("...","dropdown_menu","inverse")
    +nav_item("index.html","active") Home
    +nav_item("https://...") Chat
```

Latest header.jade:

```
extends ../node_modules/jade-bootstrap/_bootstrap
+navbar("...","dropdown_menu","inverse")
    +nav_item("index.html","active") Home
    +nav_item("https://...") Chat
```

Comment: What directory is the header.jade file in? Do you have it in a subfolder called includes, or is it in the same folder as layout.jade / home.jade?

Comment: it's the same folder as home.jade and layout.jade (views)

Comment: Can you update your post with the code you have in header.jade.

Comment: I added header.jade code to the post.

Comment: Ok so you've created a mixin somewhere? You will need to include the mixin file in your header.jade file.

Comment: I'm using jade-bootstrap and added an extends statement, see above. The statement in the documentation (http://rajasegar.github.io/JADE-Bootstrap/getting-started.html) did not work, I had to add the directory. No change, still no navbar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120508/discussion-between-peter-schleinitz-and-adam-morgan).